# Calling Code Activity Within Code Activity

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity, workflowservice

How do I execute a code activity from within a code activity?

```
public sealed class ApprovalRequired : CodeActivity
{
    EmailActivity ea = new EmailActivity() // this is a code activity
    ea.Sender = ...
    ea.Rec = ...
    ea.Subject = "Approved"
   // ea.Execute() -- there is no way to call the execute method..
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to prepare a XAML-based activity that has a sequence activity with your **ApprovalRequired** activity somewhere in it. Something like this:

[image]

Edit: To actually have an 'inner' activity be executed from another activity, your **ApprovalRequired** class should inherit from the `NativeActivity` class first, and override the **CacheMetadata** method to let the workflow application know to expect a child activity will be executed. The **ApprovalRequired** activity would look like this:

```
namespace WCA.Scratch
{
    using System.Activities;

    public sealed class ApprovalRequired : NativeActivity
    {
        public ApprovalRequired()
        {
            this.Email = new Email();
        }

        public Email Email
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        protected override void CacheMetadata(NativeActivityMetadata metadata)
        {
            metadata.AddImplementationChild(this.Email);
        }

        protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
        {
            // Some logic here...
            this.Email.Body = "My email body.";
            this.Email.From = "me@someplace.com";
            this.Email.To = "someone@someplace.com";
            this.Email.Subject = "Approval Request";
            context.ScheduleActivity(this.Email);
            // Some other logic here...
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that you'll need to manually register any activity arguments or activity variables in the **ApprovalRequired**'s `CacheMetadata` method as well.